# Import a GIMP XCF on Windows 7

Tags: image, import, windows

How do you import a GIMP XCF File into Blender when running it on windows 7?

I see all this stuff for how to do it in Linux, but is there anyway to do it with windows?

And what is this http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/GIMPImageToScene talking about?

Answer (score 1):

There is an "import GIMP" addon currently available, but it doesn't look like it's very stable at this point. You can activate it under *User Preferences > Addons > Import GIMP to scene*. Use key search word GIMP to locate it. Then it just a matter of opening the import menu, selecting xcf and importing the file. like I said though, it's kinda unstable, wait for more hardy versions to come out if you can.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that this addon is in the official addons list, as it needs xcftools to work, and currently doesn't seem to have any support for windows.

Comment: I got it to work on W7 just a few hours ago. hmmmm....

Answer (score 0):

Xcftools requires compiling, which it was designed for within a Unix environment. On windows 7/later.
Also keep an eye on the console for any errors, and what line those errors appear on while using the *Import GIMP to scene* script.  You can use Notepad++/blender's script editor to check these.

An alternative however that works just as well (as the script converts your layers to PNG's anyway):

Use the 'Export Layers' script within GIMP (you might need to search [gimp plugin registry](http://registry.gimp.org/)) [image]

It will export all of your layers into one neat folder, with each separate image named by the layer it's taken from.

Then you can use the tried and tested *Images as planes* addon that is more robust.[image]