# How do you get xcftools or an alternitave to work in windows?

Tags: import, windows, installation

there is plenty of talk about [*xcftools*](http://henning.makholm.net/xcftools/) for Linux (obviously as its only Linux compatible) but there is no mention of windows or mac. not even an alternative.

its imperative that I can work the GIMP plugin. as I do not have the money to purchase the full version of AE or PS.

I am now using GIMP and Blender as the alternative for Adobe for these, only i've ran into road block after road block. The only one which is physically stopping me from working though is the need for xcftools.

If anyone has overcome this hurdle, your wisdom would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you skipped the part where you explain what xcftools features you are looking for in Blender. Blender does have xcf loader add-on, but it does require xcftools.

Comment: I'm using Gimp and Blender on Linux and Windows, I never owned PS or any Adobe product. Could you please explain exactly why this is a Blender-related question and also please specify *exactly* where you hit road blocks.

Comment: Possibly look at the workaround listed here[win7 and xcf tools](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/import-a-gimp-xcf-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

Is the file in a .tar.gz format by any chance?

If so,I know your answer.

Simply go to a free online file converter,then change it to a .zip format and finally import it into Blender using the "Install File" button on the User Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

.xcf is simply the default save format in Gimp.  You aren't limited to saving images in that format though.  Use *Save As...* instead.  Pick an image format that's suitable for your needs.  I find .png does well.  It  has lossless-compression, and ability to use an alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, Blender has an import/export plugin for Gimp XCF, but it has a dependency that "xcftools" are installed.  However, this is not a Blender script. An archive can be downloaded, but it contains C source files that need to be compiled if I'm interpreting the contents of that archive.  The available archives are in formats that are more common to Unix/Linux, but it WinRAR seems to do fine with them.